# Variable 'minSum' is used before being assigned

Tags: typescript

```
let arrSort: number[] = arr.sort(), minSum: number;
   arrSort.forEach((a, b) => {
     if(b > 0){
       minSum += minSum + a;
       console.log(b)
     }
   })
   console.log(minSum); // Variable 'minSum' is used before being assigned.
```

minSum is defined on top but typescript still throws an error saying it
s not assigned

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to initialize `minSum` to be able to accumulate a sum there. Also you're adding twice by doing `minSum += minSum + a;`

```js
let arrSort: number[] = arr.sort(), minSum: number = 0;
   arrSort.forEach((a, b) => {
     if(b > 0){
       minSum += a;
       console.log(b)
     }
   })
   console.log(minSum); // Variable 'minSum' is used before being assigned.
```

You can play with it [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&module=100&noImplicitOverride=true&noPropertyAccessFromIndexSignature=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/DYUwLgBAhgTjDKB7GYBcEB2BXAtgIxBgG0BdCAXglIDoBnZMACgEoAaCHASw3l3W3yEKEAAwBuALAAoCLNgIG1AGbIAolADGAC0aMo7PMwoA%20CAG9psq5yWM8EUyOYWZVq1x64IAakpRJrm4QGogY9KDUwIgA5nbMlm4AvgkQifGBIWGIEVGxHrw4zGJAA)

Comment: thanks it worked!